# Blazor passing columnname parameter to component and second parameter in component

Tags: callback, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-component

So I have a div, in this div there is a Sort Component. What I want to achieve is, when I click on one of the icons from Component, it should call LoadProjects with following parameters: columnname and isAscending. It depends on the icon which is clicked, whether isAscending should be true or false. I will provide some screenshots of my code. I kinda coded it with the help of ChatGPT but I get an error.

**[Table.razor file:]**

```html
<th class="M2 border-color">
    <div class="flex ml-[25px] flex-row text">
        <span>release</span>
        <Sort columnName="projectname" OnSortClick="LoadProjects"/>
        <Filter />
    </div>
</th>
```

**[LoadProjects Method in Table.razor]**

```cs
private async Task LoadProjects(string column, bool asc)
{
    projects = await projectsService.GetProjects(column, asc);
    sortedProjects = new List<Projects>(projects);
}
```

**[Sort Componen**t]

```cs
<svg class="ml-[10px]" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="20" viewBox="0 0 16 20" fill="none">
    <path d="M8 0L14.4952 7.5H1.50481L8 0Z" fill="#C0C5CA" @onclick="HandleClickAsc" />
    <path d="M2.59926 13L8 19.2362L13.4007 13H2.59926Z" fill="#C0C5CA" stroke="#C0C5CA" @onclick="HandleClickDesc"/>
</svg>

@code{
 [Parameter] public string columnName { get; set; }
 [Parameter] public EventCallback<(string, bool)> OnSortClick { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleClickAsc()
    {
        await OnSortClick.InvokeAsync((columnName,false));
    }

    private async Task HandleClickDesc()
    {
        await OnSortClick.InvokeAsync((columnName, true));
    }
}
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve and can help me. Im a beginner in Blazor btw.

The error I get is CS1503

ChatGPT but didnt really help

Comment: Add your code to the question in code blocks and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: The problem is if I wasnt using a component, for the "Sort", i could just make a @onclick="LoadProjects("projectname", true) on arrow up icon and @onclick="LoadProjects("projectname", false) on arrow down icon. But because Im using a component I cant do it so easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're passing an anonymous tuple as the EventCallback payload.

```cs
[Parameter] public EventCallback<(string, bool)> OnSortClick { get; set; }
```

The `LoadProjects(string column, bool asc)` method cannot automatically deconstruct the tuple to your local variables. So you need to declare the parameter that the method will accept more explicitly and then you can use the `column` and `asc` variables like so.

```cs
private async Task LoadProjects((string column, bool asc) tuple)
{
    // just use it directly
    tuple.column;
    tuple.asc;
    
    // or deconstruct to local variables
    string column = tuple.column;
    bool asc = tuple.asc;
    
    // or a shorthand deconstruction
    var (column, asc) = tuple;
}
```

IMO it's not a good practice to pass tuples in EventCallbacks as it adds unnecessary complexity to the paramters, especially considering you already have the `ColumnName` as a public parameter and access to it outside of the component.

[Snippet demo](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wnlamubi003CdnlM03)

---

In the demo i've made the following changes.

1. I've changed your sort method clicks to call the same `HandleClick` method where each icon will pass a different bool parameter e.g.
   `@onclick="(e)=>HandleClick(true)"`
2. The `ColumnName` property to PascalCase as is the convention when naming public parameters in Blazor.

```cs
<svg class="ml-[10px]" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="20" viewBox="0 0 16 20" fill="none">
    <path d="M8 0L14.4952 7.5H1.50481L8 0Z" fill="#C0C5CA" @onclick="(e)=>HandleClick(true)" />
    <path d="M2.59926 13L8 19.2362L13.4007 13H2.59926Z" fill="#C0C5CA" stroke="#C0C5CA" @onclick="(e)=>HandleClick(false)"/>
</svg>

@code{
    [Parameter] public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<(string, bool)> OnSortClick { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleClick(bool isAsc)
    {
        await OnSortClick.InvokeAsync((ColumnName,isAsc));
    }
}
```